# Google-API for Objective-C: no such file or directory - libGTLTouchStaticLib.a

Tags: google-drive-api

I tried to include the Google-Api in my iOS-App. Wanted to include Google Drive.

So I followed everything on https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart .

After many hours of try-and-error it's not working at all.

It starts that the whole thing doesn't seem to be 64bit-capable and XCode will complain ...didn't contain all required architectures...". After fiddling around with different build settings I got that out of my way.

Than the howto advices only to copy two files (`GTLDrive.h` and `GTLDrive_Sources.m`) into your project. This results in the complaint `GTLDriveConstants.h` would be missing. In the end you have to copy the whole `Drive/Generated` folder into your project. After that it still complained `GTLQuery.h` would be missing, so I imported all the header-files (yes, I set the "User Header Search Paths" to the source-folder of the Google-API, doesn't help).

Next build will produce a lot of "duplicate symbol"s. After a lot of searching and finding out I had to clean up the "Compile Sources" in "Build Phases". Now that problem was solved, but now I'm stuck.

Now it complains:

> clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/#myself#/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/#my-project#-finogpkkwtusudgbuiiodrxfuxwm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a'

I got libGTLTouchStaticLib.a added to the application project's Build Phases "Link Binary with Libraries" list like adviced in the howto.

I got no more ideas. Anybody?

BTW: What a pain-in-the-ass! Dropbox-integration was so easy; import the framework - go!
Dropbox 1, Google -1.000.000

Answer (score 5):

Yes i feel your pain :D . GD is a pain to integrate.
I had faced the same problem this is how i solved it.

Before the below steps make sure you build the GTL.xcodeproject that you have added to your xcode project. once or you  wont fine the library

Go To Xcode> File Menu > Project Setting

Click on the arrow near Derived Data

In the derived data folder search for the GTL project

then go to Build->Products->Debug-iphonesimulator or -iphoneos

you will find libGTLTouchStaticLib.a

Use this in your project!

Phew !!!
Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts Nitesh, but in my DerivedData folder under

GTL-gobbledegook/Build/Products

I only find one folder "Debug", which has the "GTL.framework" in it.

The build is running successfully before...

Comment: oh did you build the GTL.xcodeproject. If its did run successfully. the library should be there. Anyways sorry couldnt help you. Worth a try though

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem when I tried to build for devices. Here is how I fixed it.

Click on the GTL.xcodeproject and go to build settings. Check if the *Architectures* is set to "*Standard architectures (armv7, armv7S, arm64)*".

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But as I wrote I fiddled around with different build settings (A LOT - I think I tried every possible setting). That didn't solve it.